# PHP Select list does not repopulate in case an error is shown

Tags: php

I have a `<select>` list of names I'm getting from another function:

```
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
    <?php
        $users->view_team($username);
    ?>
</select>
```

If in any way relevant, here is the `view_team()` function inside my users.php file:

```
public function view_team($username) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `manager`= ? ORDER BY `lastname` ASC ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $i = 0;

    try{
        $query->execute();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            $i++;
            echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$i.') '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['firstname']."</option>";

        }
    $this->queryResult = $query->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

My problem is when an error is generated by an input in a field. Basically I'm showing some error messages, something like this if a user enters faulty inputs:

```
if (!is_numeric($amount)) {
    $errors[] = 'Ooops ! Amount value must be a number.';
}
```

The error messages are shown on the same page:

```
<?php 
    if(empty($errors) === false){
        echo '<p> ' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>'; 
    }
?>
```

My list of employees I'm showing does not repopulate when an error is generated. How do I make it repopulate ?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't repopulate on page reload. Try to var_dump() $users and $username when submitting a bad input.

Comment: It seems I was foolishly overwriting a core variable and these lists got populated according to that. They repopulate just fine now. I think your suggestion was good anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to change the name of a variable. Sorry for the misunderstanding.